# pandas group-by if values doesn't change for a certain period of time

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a huge Dataframe like this:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'date': ["2020-10-1 12:00:00", "2020-10-2 12:00:00", "2020-10-3 12:00:00", "2020-10-4 12:00:00",
                                "2020-10-5 12:00:00", "2020-10-6 12:00:00", "2020-10-7 12:00:00", "2020-10-8 12:00:00",
                                "2020-10-9 12:00:00"],
                       'revenue_A': [100, 250, 300, 300, 300, 300, 200, 100, 300],
                       'revenue_B': [100, 200, 200, 200, 200, 300, 250, 100, 200]})
```

I want to split the Dataframe if revenue_A and revenue_B don't change for at least certain number of (e.g. 48) consecutive hours. The expected result would be:

```
                 date  revenue_A  revenue_B
0  2020-10-1 12:00:00        100        100
1  2020-10-2 12:00:00        250        200
2  2020-10-3 12:00:00        300        200
3  2020-10-4 12:00:00        300        200
4  2020-10-5 12:00:00        300        200
```

and

```
                 date  revenue_A  revenue_B
5  2020-10-6 12:00:00        300        300
6  2020-10-7 12:00:00        200        250
7  2020-10-8 12:00:00        100        100
8  2020-10-9 12:00:00        300        200
```

Any idea how this is efficiently possible (Dataframe has millions of rows).

Comment: Thanks for providing a good usable example. I'm just having trouble aligning your example split with the explanation above. Why do you put the split between rows 5 and 6, when B has just changed from 200 to 300?

Comment: I think it's because between rows 5->6->7, A changes from 300->200->100, and B changes from 300->250->100 : so, 2 consecutive changes!
Although probably the OP can confirm this!

Comment: @Arne, you are right! it should split at row 4...I fixed the question!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's efficient enough, but here is one way to do this:

```py
# compute row indices at which to split
splits = [i for i in range(2, len(df)) 
          if (df.revenue_A[i-2] == df.revenue_A[i-1] == df.revenue_A[i]
          and df.revenue_B[i-2] == df.revenue_B[i-1] == df.revenue_B[i])] 

# sort in descending order
splits.sort(reverse=True)

# initialize list of subframes
subframes = []

# traverse rows backwards, so that we can add the subframe after the split point
# to the subframe list and drop it from the main frame without messing up the
# remaining indices
for split in splits:
    if split < len(df) - 1:
        subframes.append(df[split+1:])
        df = df.drop(range(split+1, len(df)))

# also add the last remaining subframe to the list
subframes.append(df)
```

Comment: It wouldn't do it since the datetimes can have varying periodicity! Sometimes there are observations every 2 hours! The solution should work with date column as well!

Comment: @Morty okay, could you provide a data sample that includes these quirks? And are you sure you don't want to group by day first of all, to make the data more uniform and manageable?